# Let \pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{-1} output minus sign “−” instead of hyphen minus “-”

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

The `\pgfmathprintnumber` command from the `tikz` package is rather handy to achieve consistent number formatting throughout a large document. When setting `assume math mode=true`, this even works in text mode, if the formatting does not require explicit math features like subscripts.

Unfortunately, using `\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]` in text mode on negative numbers only produced a hyphen minus “-”. Is it possible to let it produce a minus sign “−” instead? I am using LuaLaTeX, so Unicode characters are not a problem.

Comment: what happens when you type `-` and `${}-{}$` in your document? This sounds like a font issue rather than pgf problem.

Comment: Typing `-` produces a hyphen minus in the text font and typing `${}-{}$` produces a minus sign in the math font. What I would like to achieve with `\pgfmathprintnumber` is to output the number and a real minus sign in text font.